# how to automatically set prompt colour in Bash based upon hostname

Tags: bash, ansi-colors

I want to have a standard BASH PS1 prompt that will automatically have a colour set based upon the hostname of the server.

This would meant that whenever logging into a server, it would instantly be clear and familiar that you are on that server as the prompt colour would be different to other servers

A given hostname must always give the same colour

I have found similar ideas with hex codes, but this is specifically for use with BASH colours

The idea would then be that there can be a standard bash prompt code snippet that can be included everywhere and will always give different colours for different servers without any further code changes

In a nutshell, the question is what bash function could you write that will take 2 arguments - a string and a hash. It should echo out the string in a colour that is determined by the hash, and the colour should always be the same for any given hash

EDIT - TO CLARIFY

the answers so far assume that host names are known in advance

I am looking for something that will assign the same random colour deterministically based on whatever host name is for that server

I am definitely not looking for something that requires any kind of code change when installing the PS1 on a new server

This post is along the lines but doesn't seem to have a simple PS1 snippet that I can use https://aweirdimagination.net/2015/02/28/better-hash-based-colors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am looking for something that will assign the same random colour deterministically based on whatever host name is for that server

Take a hashing algorithm and compute the hash of the hostname - as to convert a string to numbers. Then use this pseudorandom-number to generate a color.

```
gen_prompt_function() {
   local number
   number=$(
       # get "random" string that depends on hostname
       md5sum <<<"$HOSTNAME" |
       # meh - take first byte and convert it to decimal
       cut -c-2 | xargs -i printf "%d\n" "0x{}" |
       # convert 0-255 range into 30-37 range
       awk '{print int($0/255.0*(37-30)+30)}'
  )
  printf '\[\e[%d;1m\]%s\[\e[m\]' "$number" "$HOSTNAME"
}
PS1="$(gen_prompt_function)"'$ '
```

Read [ANSI escpe sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), [tput](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tput.1.html) and about [color handling in terminfo](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html) and [bash manual controlling prompt](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html). Remember to add `\[` `\]` around color codes.

PS. In my bash adventures solely for hostname prompt coloring I have written a [color handling script](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamilscripts/-/blob/master/bin/,color) that generates a rainbow from 3 RGB colors taken from first 18 characters extracted from hash of a string, like in screeshot below. That script is used in my [PS1 configuration](https://gitlab.com/Kamcuk/kamilscripts/-/blob/master/etc/bash.d/ps1.sh#L52).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```sh
declare -A color=([hosty]=33 [hostr]=31 [hostb]=34 [hostm]=35)
function color () {
    host=$1
    printf $'\e[%d;1m%s\e[m' "${color[$host]}" "$host"
}

PS1='$(color $HOSTNAME)$ '
```

Answer (score 1):

Determine what the host name is, then define `PS1`.

```
case $HOSTNAME in
  foo.com) color='...' ;;
  bar.org) color='...' ;;
esac

PS1="..."   # using $color as necessary
```